# HijriCalendar calculate Ramadan Feast

Tags: c#, date, calendar

I try to calculate the ramadan feast. I use the HijriCalendar for this issue.
I have check [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_Turkey) and ramadan feast is on the end of the islamic month Ramadan.

Some dates are good but other on the wrong day (1 day deferred)

```
var hijriCalendar = new HijriCalendar();

for (var i = 1431; i <= 1438; i++)
{
    var dateTime = new DateTime(i, 10, 1, hijriCalendar);
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
}
```

**Public Holiday Ramadan Feast**
First value calculated, second the correct value

- 2010-09-09 (2010-09-09)
- 2011-08-30 (2011-08-30)
- 2012-08-18 (2012-08-19) **WRONG +1**
- 2013-08-07 (2013-08-08) **WRONG +1**
- 2014-07-28 (2014-07-28)
- 2015-07-17 (2015-07-17)
- 2016-07-06 (2016-07-05) **WRONG -1**
- 2017-06-25 (2017-07-25)

Source of correct date
https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/turkey/ramadan-feast

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the C# HijriCalendar acknowledges that the dates of Ramadan can be off and offers a `HijriCalendar.HijriAdjustment` Property to account for variances from year to year.

> This implementation of the HijriCalendar class adjusts the calendar
>   date by adding or subtracting a value from zero to two days to
>   accommodate the variances in the start and the end of Ramadan and to
>   accommodate the date difference between countries/regions

Check out this page for more information about it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.hijricalendar.hijriadjustment(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If it set the HijriAdjustment to a other value the dates of other years a wrong.

Comment: I cannot be sure, but the little bit I read seemed to suggest that Ramadan changes from year to year, and from region to region, in such a way that the HijriCalandar doesn't account for all those variances. It could be that c# expects the developer to know the day of Ramadan, and use the adjustment value to correct the data. Maybe someone with more calendar experience could chime in about this.